# Best way to pass around large amount of data into functions

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I'm working on a large project where in a first instance information is gathered about what needs to be done. Most of that information then needs to be passed into a calculator.

At present, this is done via a large dictionary which is passed from function to function and new keys are added without any rule. The result is that nobody knows what and where things are in that dictionary.

What would be a better way to do that in python? What other viable options are there to pass around the data to the endpoint, but in a more structured way, so that only certain keys are allowed to be set in the dictionary and can only have certain values?

Here an example of what I mean:

```
def gather_data(data):
    data['one'] = 1


def manipulate_data(data):
    data['two'] = 2
    data['whatever'] = 3


def calculate(data):
    result = data['one'] + data['two']
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {}
    gather_data(data)
    manipulate_data(data)
    result = calculate(data)
    print(result)
```

Comment: We had a [tag:best-practices] tag that we burninated. This question falls outside the scope of questions that are on topic as described in the help centre. As a user with nearly 1k rep, you should know that...

Comment: Rephrased the question with an example,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that a singleton with properties might be the best way:
""" Contains configuration classes that can be instantiated wherever needed """

```
class Singleton(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(Singleton, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
        cls.instance = None

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if cls.instance is None:
            cls.instance = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
        return cls.instance


class Configuration(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    def __init__(self):
        self.mode = None
        self.system = None
```

Configuration can then be imported and instantiated and edited wherever needed and it will kepp it's state.